# Interpretation of ACF plot of a Hidden Markov Model

Tags: r, dataset, autocorrelation, markov-process, acf-pacf

I am trying to interpret the ACF plot of a 3 state HMM model but as it is my first time dealing with any kind of HMM it is causing a lot of trouble. I have also had a hard time finding a ressource on the subject of ACF plots.

From my understanding we are trying to 'counteract' some autocorrelation that is present in the data. This would happen if we observe white noise(?!). However, I have no idea other than this simple observation which might be wrong.

[image]

**Question**: What can I interpret from the given ACF plot of the HMM?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.